# Datos se borran de un objeto en Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

Tengo un objeto declarado de la siguiente forma:

```
    nroRacional = object
    private
        primerNro:double;
        segundoNro:double;
    public
        procedure cargarDatos(primerDato, segundoDato:double);
        function sumar():double;
    end;
```

Con sus respectivas funciones

```
procedure nroRacional.cargarDatos(primerDato, segundoDato:double);
begin
    primerNro := primerDato;
    segundoNro := segundoDato;
end;
function nroRacional.sumar():double;
begin
    sumar := primerNro + segundoNro;
end;
```

Tengo un botón con el que cargo los datos, y también hace la suma sin problema

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  racional:nroRacional;
  primerNro, segundoNro, suma:double;
begin
  primerNro := strtofloat(Edit1.Text);
  segundoNro := strtofloat(Edit2.Text);
  racional.cargarDatos(primerNro, segundoNro);
  suma := racional.sumar();
  memo1.Lines.Add(suma.tostring);
end;
```

Hasta acá todo bien, si quiero hacer una suma de 2+2, me da que el resultado es 4. Pero yo quiero eliminar las dos últimas líneas de ese botón, y hacerlo en otro botón, que tengo escrito de la siguiente forma:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    racional:nroRacional;
    primerNro, segundoNro, suma:double;
begin
    suma := racional.sumar();
    memo1.Lines.Add(suma.ToString);
end;
```

Pero al querer hacer la suma con este botón, el resultado me da "2,1972521620272E-307"
¿Cómo puedo corregir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como has escrito el código, cada método tiene su propia variable local (el nombre o el hecho de que ambas variables se llamen igual es irrelevante). El ámbito de cada una de estas variables es solamente dicho método, por lo que al llegar al `end;` dejan de existir (con los valores que pudieran tener).

Las variables de tipo *objeto* residen en el `Stack`, cuya memoria no es inicializada, de manera que al entrar a una rutina y declarar sus variables, estas residen en direcciones de memoria que tienen información aleatoria (también llamada *basura*).

Tomando en cuenta esto, en el manejador de evento del segundo botón, no has inicializado el *objeto* `racional`, y llamas a su *método* `sumar();`, que opera con la *basura* que está almacenada en sus miembros `primerNro` y `segundoNro`. El valor que te devuelve es la suma de los valores que están en dichos miembros. Este valor puede cambiar entre una ejecución del programa y otra. Al operar sobre basura, el resultado es indefinido.

Lo primero, entonces, es que inicialices el *objeto*, tal como lo haces en el manejador del primer botón, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  Racional: nroRacional;
begin
  Racional.cargarDatos(strtofloat(Edit1.Text), strtofloat(Edit2.Text));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(racional.sumar().ToString());
end;
```

Por otro lado, si quieres *compartir* el objeto entre los distintos métodos del formulario, puedes declararlo como miembro de la clase `TForm1`, de manera que ahora reside dentro de la clase, se crea y se destruye junto a cada instancia del formulario, por ejemplo:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FRacional: nroRacional;
  public
    //bla, bla, bla
  end;

implementation
//bla,bla,bla
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRacional.cargarDatos(strtofloat(Edit1.Text), strtofloat(Edit2.Text));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(racional.sumar().ToString());
end;
```

Ahora, si presionas los botones en secuencia, en el Botón 1 le asignas los valores de los edits, y el el botón 2 realizas la invocación del método `sumar()`, sobre el mismo objeto.

Dicho esto, quiero finalizar comentando que:

- Los tipos `object` se consideran obsoletos y se mantienen en el lenguaje solo por compatibilidad con código **muy viejo**.

  La recomendación es utilizar directamente clases que, junto a `TObject`, son la base del modelo de POO de Object Pascal, o utilizar estructuras tipo registros que, a estas alturas, pueden tener métodos asociados, muy a lo *objeto*.
- Por convención, los identificadores de tipos de dato, particularmente en el ámbito de POO en Delphi, suelen comenzar con la letra `T`, tal como `TObject`, `TComponent`, `TClass`, `TForm`, etc.

  Nada te obliga a seguir la convención, pero hacerlo tiene el beneficio de que se te hará más natural leer código escrito por otros, así como mas fácil para otros entender el código escrito por ti, si todos siguen las convenciones.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Se me había pasado por alto que había declarado el objeto localmente dos veces.

Answer (score 1):

Los datos no se borran. Nunca estuvieron allí.

En el primer código, creas una variable local de tipo `nroRacional`, inicializas los campos y operas con ella.

En el segundo código, creas **otra** variable local de tipo `nroRacional` y operas con ella sin inicializar los campos.

Las variables locales son eso, locales. Aunque tengan el mismo nombre, no hay ninguna relación entre `racional` de `TForm1.Button1Click` y `racional` de `TForm1.Button2Click`.

Para operar con la segunda variable, tendrás que inicializarla, o de alguna forma (¿variables globales? Aunque eso se suele desaconsejar) pasar una referencia o copia del primer objeto al segundo método.